# Relationship Properties in Graph Database Are Relationships

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am new to graph databases and I am trying to understand how to create relationships who have relationships.

For example: We could take a movie. Jennifer Lawrence Acted in The Hunger Games Playing the Character Katniss Everdeen.

In this case, how would you note that Jennifer Lawrence Acted in The Hunger Games, Katniss Everdeen was a character in The Hunger Games, and Jennifer Lawrence Played Katniss Everdeen. You could add a property in the acted in relationship that would be "Character". But I also want Character to be a Node so you could look for the Character Katniss Everdeen in Movies/Books etc.

What would be the best way to organize that? Could you create the Acted In Relationship where the property character in the relationship was linked to a Character Labeled Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use an intermediate node that represents the `Role`, which pertains to the character, actor and the movie:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have the need for a relationship pointing to a relationship, introduce a node. In your example I'd introduce a node representing the action of acting in a movie. It has (at least) three relationships of different type: one to the Actor (Jennifer Lawrence), one to the Movie (The Hunger Games) and one to the Character (Katniss Everdeen).

With the additional node you've basically simulated an hyperedge (aka a relationship connecting more than two nodes).